# draw.io %varaible% titleblock text substition in a multisheet document

Tags: properties, substitution, draw.io

Problem:  want to set a document local variable once (using CTRL+M) ONCE and then re-use the %var% in a common title block used on EVERY sheet in THIS document

Seems you can export CTRL+M properties, but can not import them!

[image]
[image]

at present CTRL+M sheet properties are only local to the sheet, and not the document

Hypothetical, Would there be a way to reference a property from one sheet (eg sheet 1 of N) on all other sheets using the CTRL+M "ID" field = "YnHH....vHi" ?

The only other substitution %var% options are global to the App  (using menu extras\configuration:
{
"globalVars": {
"Company": "Restech"
}
}

Comment: Hi. I'm looking for the exact same thing. Any luck so far ?